# Do these two (relatively less common) definitions of $e^x$ extend to the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Consider the following two (relatively less common) definitions of the exponential function $e^x: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

1. Define $e^x$ by the limit:

$$
e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n
$$

2. Define $e^x$ as the unique number $y > 0$ such that
   $$
   \int_1^y \frac{dt}{t} = x
   $$

**Question:** Do these definitions extend to the complex plane as well (that is, do they make sense if we let $x = z \in \mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: Yes for the first one and no to the second one.  If the second method only works for $y>0$, how do you expect it to work for $y\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: Worth pointing out that the binomial expansion of $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Doug M in the comments above, the binomial expansion of your first example is neatly given as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$, which is the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ by definition.  This expansion analytically extends to any value of $x\in\mathbb C$.  Since the limit converges for all $x\in\mathbb C$, it must converge to $e^x$.

Your second example, however, only works for $y>0$, and so by nature it cannot extend to $x\in\mathbb C$.  The reason is because the integral of $\frac1t$ is not defined over $t=0$. (as you probably noted)  If you did attempt to calculate around the singularity, you would get false statements like $e^0=-1$.

Comment: How do you get $e^0=-1$? If you interpret $\int_{1}^y\frac{dt}{t}=x$ as calling for an integral along an arbitrary path from $1$ to $y$ in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, the definition works out fine.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I couldn't do that, so I treated it as $\lim_{a\to0}\int_{-1}^a+\int_a^1$.  I imagined you could work it out, but that was beyond me and probably beyond the OP.